# Почему команда 'ls' c ключами в Windows Terminal выдает ошибку?

Tags: консоль, windows-10

В Windows 10   открыл программу   Windows Terminal, из Microsoft Store, пробую вводить команду ls c ключами - 'ls -l'  и пр. - вместо списка файлов появляется сообщение об ошибке (см скриншот).Подскажите, в чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: ls в этом контексте не имеет отношения к core utls

Comment: Кроме скриншота нужно приводить и текстовое содержание ошибки, что бы другие люди могли находить поиском данный вопрос.

Comment: Я ввожу команду   -  'ls'     #List the contents of a folder# - выдается список каталогов и папок в рабочей директории(забыл вывести ls без ключа в скриншоте), а когда ввожу - 'ls -al'  #List all the contents of a folder with info#  не выдается(ошибка) список windows команд отсюда: https://realpython.com/terminal-commands/

Comment: команды по ссылке не имеют отношения к powershell, там команды core utils